# Git push error: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: bash, git

I pushed two commit changes, then it turned out I had to pull some changes that a coworker made. When I try to push I get this error:

```
>>> /usr/bin/git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/main
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Failed sending data to the peer
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Solutions I've tried without success:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do this

1. delete .git/ from your project
2. clone the remote `repo` to some new location like your desktop:

3.`git clone https://github.com/foo/bar.git`

4.move .git/ from the new location into the old location
re-commit and push your changes